# is it possible to record video in Flex without streaming to a server

Tags: apache-flex, streaming, video-capture

I want to give my users the ability to record a video from WebCam (maximum 60 seconds) so the file should be big with proper quality settings.

Do you know of a way to record it in memory (as Flash running in browser can't access file System) and then send it to server to save the file?

I have build a functionality to capture a photo with Webcam and send it to the server but not sure about Video.

(I prefer not to stream to Red5/FMS or similar as it's more relaible to keep things contained in the Flash file in my opinion) plus I had issues with quality of recording with Red5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tam,

Flash player 10.1 has facility to access Microphone and record auio without connecting to streaming server but, I don't think it still has the same for videos.

so for the time being, you can not record video without connecting to streaming server like Red5 or FMS.

not sure though, technology changes every moment! ;-)